# Laravel query builder with AND in query

Tags: php, laravel-3

I want to add an "AND" clause to the end of a query builder, the code looks like this:

```
$orderers = DB::table('address')->where(function($query) use ($term) {
                            $query->where('id', 'LIKE', '%' . $term . '%')
                                    ->or_where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $term . '%')
                                    ->or_where('status', 'LIKE', '%' . $term . '%')
                                    ->and_clause_goes_here('is_orderer', '=', '1');
                        })->paginate($per_page);
```

But searching for a AND clause in Laravel I couldn't find any of equivalent. Could you help me with this problem?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

JCS solution may still yield some unexpected results due to the order of operations. You should group all the OR's together as you would in SQL, explicitly defining the logic. It also makes it easier to understand for the next time you ( or to another team member ), when they read the code.

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE a = 'a' 
AND (
    WHERE b = 'b'
    OR WHERE c = 'c'
)
AND WHERE d = 'd'


Foo::where( 'a', '=', 'a' )
    ->where( function ( $query )
    {
        $query->where( 'b', '=', 'b' )
            ->or_where( 'c', '=', 'c' );
    })
    ->where( 'd', '=', 'd' )
    ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. and I think it must be `orWhere` not `or_where`. It caused an error in laravel 5.5.

Answer (score 16):

simply another where clause will do, AND will be use

```
$orderers = DB::table('address')->where(function($query) use ($term) {
                            $query->where('id', 'LIKE', '%' . $term . '%')
                                    ->where('is_orderer', '=', '1');
                                    ->or_where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $term . '%')
                                    ->or_where('status', 'LIKE', '%' . $term . '%')
                        })->paginate($per_page);
```